# Different scope of custom exception type in doctest when run by PyCharm. Why?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, python-import, doctest

I have a function raising a custom exception type. To my own annoyance my pedantic nature lets me want a docstring containing a doctest snippet:

```
# my_package/my_module.py

class Mayday(ValueError): pass

def raisins():
    """
    >>> raisins()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    my_module.Mayday: Yikes!
    """
    raise Mayday('Yikes!')

# EOF, i.e. nothing calling doctest.testmethod() explicitly
```

Now, this works fine when run within my local PyCharm using an automatically created run configuration (Run 'Doctests in my_module'). It fails basically anywhere else, i.e. when invoking `python -m pytest --doctest-modules` (under various environments). The problem is the scope of the exception type which then prepends the package name:

```
Expected: ... my_module.Mayday: Yikes!
Got: ... my_package.my_module.Mayday: Yikes!
```

Interestingly calling `raisins()` within the PyCharm provided Python console (which means it should use the very same environment) yields an exception type *including* the package name and by this - in a way - contradicts itself.

There must be a difference in invoking doctest I am not aware of. What is it?

Like every good programmer I adapted the tests so everything is green now. +cough+ Still this is not really a satisfying solution. Is there a way to succeed both ways (maybe by a clever way to import within the docstring)?

Comment: `my_package.my_module.Mayday` is the correct qualname of your exception. The issue is probably in project configuration in Pycharm, where you've set the content root to be `my_package` - it should be its parent directory instead (the first one that doesn't contain an `__init__.py`).